# ASP.Net MVC and 14 Rules of Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

Is there something similar for ASP.Net MVC like [this plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ui-performance) for Grails that implements most of the [14 Rules for great performing websites](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rules.php)?

Comment: There are lots of individual tools to accomplish most of these in an automated way. Of course, some require manual adjustments anyway. MVC4 is supposed to add minification builtin. But I am not aware of any tool that combines even most of these in one package... yet.

Answer (score 1):

Though this will not do the work for you, these tools will point out what problems you have: You can use in your browser, (FF for example) the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) add-on and also [Google´s Page Speed](http://www.googlelabs.com/show_details?app_key=agtnbGFiczIwLXd3d3IVCxIMTGFic0FwcE1vZGVsGNHDvAIM).

There is also [a great post](http://encosia.com/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/) in [Encosia](http://encosia.com) about combining and minifying Js files in VS.

Comment: Yes I know that, but this is not about analyzing tools like YSlow.